# Xamarin - post request with BsonMediaTypeFormatter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I want to post http request to invoke WebAPI with data as BSON format like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{                
    // Post data as BSON format
    var bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
    var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data, bsonFormatter);
}
```

It works fine with .Net framework 4.5.

However it does not work with Xamarin Android platform as it does not support BsonMediaTypeFormatter type.

So the question is how to get it works with Xamarin platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up with following solution to use `ByteArrayContent` along with the `Content-Type` header:

```
public static async HttpResponseMessage PostBson<T>(string url, T data)
{    
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Specifiy 'Accept' header As BSON: to ask server to return data as BSON format
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));                    

                //Specify 'Content-Type' header: to tell server which format of the data will be posted
                //Post data will be as Bson format                
                var bSonData = HttpExtensions.SerializeBson<T>(data);
                var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(bSonData);
                byteArrayContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson");

                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, byteArrayContent);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                return response;
            }           
}
```

The method to help serialize `BSON data` using `JSON.Net`:

```
public static byte[] SerializeBson<T>(T obj)
{
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (BsonWriter writer = new BsonWriter(ms))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
                }

                return ms.ToArray();                
            }
 }
```

Comment: I would love to use this, but keep getting the following error when posting to a Web API - even though I added             config.Formatters.Add(new BsonMediaTypeFormatter());to the WebApiConfig.cs configuration file:  Message, The request entity's media type 'application/bson' is not supported for this resource.   ExceptionMessage, No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'BlobFile' from content with media type 'application/bson'.

Comment: If anyone else comes across this, my fix involved adding the formatter to "GlobalConfiguration" in the public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) method of the WebAPI's "Startup" class instead of adding it inside app.UseWebApi(WebApiConfig.Register()); Here's the full line:  System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.BsonMediaTypeFormatter()); Microsoft's docs show it added in the Register() method within the WebAPIConfg class, but that did not work for me.  I happened across a July 2012 article by Filip W on StrathWeb that gave me the clue.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find a Xamarin compatible BSON (de)serializer and use it to serialize the data prior to sending. Something like this:

```
var content = BsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
var response = await client.PostAsync(
    url, 
    new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/bson"));
```

For example Json.NET seems to support BSON data. Of course you can always just use JSON in Xamarin projects if using BSON gets too complicated.

Comment: Thanks but this does not work with StringContent. I have to use ByteArrayContent instead.